# Can I set my virt-manager/QEMU VM (using virgl) to 144Hz?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt, wayland

I've created a Ubuntu 21.04 VM in virt-manager and I've set the graphics to use virgl instead of QXL because it's meant to be much smoother in the desktop. While it works fine, dragging windows about feels janky, probably because the screen refresh rate is set to 74.94Hz for some reason. I can't find any solid info on how to create a custom resolution is [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland-xorg/), but it didn't work. Is virgl meant to be this janky or can I fix it?